# this keyword lost its reference to current module

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am working on a BackboneJS module. In the view I am applying a plugin to the current element. I am passing an options object `setOptions` that is setup as a property of the current view. In this object I am also calling a function `this.foo`. But it gives me the following error: `foo of undefined`. Below is my code.

```
var b = Backbone.View.extend({

    setOptions: {
        opt1: 'Option 1',
        opt2: 'Option 2',
        opt3: 'Option 3',
        opt4: 'Option 4',
        callback: this.foo // this returns foo of undefined
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.setPlugin();
    },

    setPlugin: function () {
        this.$el.pluginName(this.setOptions);
    },

    foo: function () {
        console.log('FOO');
    }

});
```

To solve this I wrote a function `setOptions`. and return object literal that sets up options for plugin. This time the function `this.foo` calls successfully but in `foo` the reference to `this` points  to `this.$el`. **I want this keyword to point to current module not that element.** I need this because I want to call more functions inside `foo` but I cannot as reference to this keyword is changed. **How can I do this?**

below is my code for second attempt

```
var b = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.setPlugin();
    },

    setPlugin: function () {
        this.$el.pluginName(this.setOptions());
    },

    setOptions: function () {
        return {
            opt1: 'Option 1',
            opt2: 'Option 2',
            opt3: 'Option 3',
            opt4: 'Option 4',
            callback: this.foo
        }
    },

    foo: function () {
        // here "this" reference to this.$el but not current module
        console.log('FOO');
    }

});
```

Comment: What is `pluginName`? jquery plugin?

Comment: Yes it is jquery plugin.

Comment: AFAIU `foo` is intentend to be called from jquery plugin constructor. In this case you cannot change the context of `this` in `foo` callback since it entirely depends on how the plugin invoke it. Apparently the plugin invoke `foo` in the context of the DOM-element binded with the plugin. So the only way change the context of `this` is modify the plugin's code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't reference properties of the object from the same object until the object is created. Thus in your case when the view object is being constructed and it comes to line `callback: this.foo` there is no such property created in the object yet. Hence the error.

The simplest workaround is to use getter function:

```
setOptions: function() {
    return {
        opt1: 'Option 1',
        opt2: 'Option 2',
        opt3: 'Option 3',
        opt4: 'Option 4',
        callback: _.bind(this.foo, this)
    }
},
```

and use it like this:

```
setPlugin: function () {
    this.$el.pluginName(this.setOptions());
},
```

Comment: I am already using that solution. But it also has a problem. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: @2619 Try `callback: _.bind(this.foo, this)` to bind `this.foo` to module context.

Comment: I tried that but now I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening (*check out the comments*):

```
// Fake "plugin" function.
function pluginName(options) {
  // Here I'm setting the 'this' value of 'foo' to the document body.
  options.callback.call(document.body);

  // Here the 'this' value would be the 'options' object because I'm calling 
  // the method through the 'options' object itself.
  /* options.callback(); */

  // If I did the following instead, the 'this' value of 'foo' would
  // be the global object, which is the 'window' object. That's because 
  // any function that's not called by a specific object is automatically 
  // executed in the context of the 'window' object.
  // var fn = options.callback;
  /* fn(); */
}

var view = {
  initialize: function () {
    this.setPlugin();
  },

  setPlugin: function () {
    pluginName(this.setOptions());
  },

  setOptions: function () {
    return {
      opt1: 'Option 1',
      opt2: 'Option 2',
      opt3: 'Option 3',
      opt4: 'Option 4',

      // 'foo' here is called by the plugin, and its 
      // 'this' value depends on how the plugin calls it.
      callback: this.foo
    }
  },

  foo: function () {
    console.log('FOO');

    // The 'this' value here depends on how the plugin calls 'foo'; in this example it is the document body.
    console.log(this);
  }
};
```

Here is a fix:

```
// Fake "plugin" function.
function pluginName(options) {
  options.callback.call(document.body);
}

var view = {
  initialize: function () {
    this.setPlugin();
  },

  setPlugin: function () {
    pluginName(this.setOptions());
  },

  setOptions: function () {
    return {
      opt1: 'Option 1',
      opt2: 'Option 2',
      opt3: 'Option 3',
      opt4: 'Option 4',

      // The 'bind' method creates an other callback for you, by making 
      // the 'this' value equal to whatever you pass it as the first argument.
      callback: this.foo.bind(this) // or use Underscore's '_.bind()' method as mentioned below.
    }
  },

  foo: function () {
    console.log('FOO');
    console.log(this); // 'this' here is the 'view' object.
  }
};
```

Here is another fix:

```
// Fake "plugin" function.
function pluginName(options) {
  options.callback.call(document.body);
}

var view = {
  initialize: function () {
    this.setPlugin();
  },

  setPlugin: function () {
    pluginName(this.setOptions());
  },

  setOptions: function () {
    var self = this;

    return {
      opt1: 'Option 1',
      opt2: 'Option 2',
      opt3: 'Option 3',
      opt4: 'Option 4',

      // Similar to the 'bind' method but manually.
      callback: function() {
        self.foo();
      }
    }
  },

  foo: function () {
    console.log('FOO');
    console.log(this); // 'this' here is the 'view' object.
  }
};
```